# Get all keys on the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering if it's possible to get all the keys for all the widgets that are on screen at once. Can this be achieved? If so, how?

Comment: yes. traverse widget tree and get the keys.

Comment: That's not something I can do on the fly while debugging, right?

Comment: You can. You can run execute code in debugger.

Comment: Most widgets do not have keys.  They are identified in a List<Widget> by type and position, which works enough of the time.